# Can t find the xpath for Following button instagram for selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, bots, instagram

I try to get the xpath for the following button on instagram making an automate unfollowing soft. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnb3V.png)

I found it just like this:

```js
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="qF0y9 Igw0E   rBNOH   YBx95   ybXk5 _4EzTm soMvl "]').click()
```

But i want to itterate over all ,,Following" Buttons , but like this is stuck at the first one!
This is my Code:

```js
fBody  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']")  
for i in range(1, 1500):
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="             qF0y9          Igw0E   rBNOH          YBx95   ybXk5    _4EzTm                      soMvl                                                                                        "]').click()
            #driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Following']").click()
            print("Am apasat follow")
            sleep(5)
            
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="aOOlW -Cab_   "]').click()
            sleep(5)
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
            print("Ma bag la somn 1 min")
            sleep(2)
print("salut")
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does Not "like" empty or white spaces in the attributes.

I suggest using a CSS selector and using `*=` in order to find text contains:

```
driver.find_element_by_CSS('//div[class*="qF0y9"][class*="Igw0E"]').click();
```

Avoid using white or empty spaces and, underscores (_) and hyphens (-) for the element's attributes.

Comment: It worked, but how i can itterate over all Follow buttons?

Comment: i = driver.find_element_by_CSS('//div[class*="qF0y9"][class*="Igw0E"]').click();
for x in i:  do stuff

Comment: @Tal Angel dont you need to remove the ; in .click(); ?

Comment: It s making like 10 actions, after that i need to scroll down to make for all followers

Comment: @SergiuBRC No, keep the ; after the click()

Answer (score 0):

I think the classes on the elements change as yours do not match with mine. Here is a more generic XPath that matches the "following" button.

```
//div//button[div[text()='Following']
```

When using this in a test I found it instantly failing unless I surrounded it with an explicit wait condition.

`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div//button[div[text()='Following']"))).click();`

Ill post my example when Instagram stops giving me connectivity issues.

Comment: It worked like this, but after 10 actions i need it to scroll down to find againg the ,,Following" button. Do you have any idea how i can do that?

Comment: Are you asking how to go through each "Following" button clicking on each one?

Comment: yes thats what i am asking for